# How to add record in table in windows form application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, data-binding

i am working on some data entry program in windows form, i write the following code on button click event to add records in table but records doesn't add it gives me an error of execute non query

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{             
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JASMEETSINGH-PC;Initial Catalog=Desnet;Integrated Security=True"); 
    con.Open();   
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into BillEntry values('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.DataBindings + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker2.DataBindings + "', '" + radioButton1.DataBindings + "', '" + radioButton2.DataBindings                 + "', '" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "','" + textBox9.Text + "','" + textBox10.Text + "')", con);     
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
    if (i > 0)           
    {                 
        label15.Text = "Record Added Successfully";            
    } 
}
```

data type used:-
varchar(10)
varchar(100)
varchar(20)
date
varchar(25)
date
char(3)
float
float
float
varchar(20)
varchar(50)
float

Comment: can you tell us exactly what the error is that you are getting?

Comment: just put all your statements in a try catch block and find the error. hope this helps

Comment: @Jasmeet Singh : Instead of giving `TextBox1`, `TextBox2` ... etc Kindly give some relevant names for better readability and share what kind of error you got.

Answer (score 0):

check the single and double quotation may be problem lies in their foe string value we use '""' but for int